# Deep Q-Learning model, Neural Network won't train

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a DQN tic-tac-toe game model using pytorch.

1. Our state is a 1x9 tensor or our game board and actions include all the playable moves (which includes 1 to 8 positions in our board). Only after both players making a move we try to get our next state
2. Player 1(which plays first) is our DQN agent and Player -1 is a random bot the plays a random valid move(move that is not played before), also the board is a 1x9 tensor containing all zero values(0 corresponds to a blank cell, 1 for our agent and -1 for random bot)
3. there are 2 neural networks, (a) Policy network(network that is trained) (b) Target network(from where we fetch next state q values)
4. the reward system rewards Player X with +1 if it wins, -1 if it loses, 0 for a draw, and a reward of 0.5 is given for every safe move played(which I think should be eliminated)
5. for a certain batch size initially, every move played with its associated reward and next state are stored in a replay memory for later training
6. am using epsilon greedy strategy meaning the first few moves taken by our agent are going to be random but after a certain decay it will start taking actions based on its policy network

   ```
    class DQN(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=9, out_features=32)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=64)
            self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=9)

        def forward(self, t):
            t = torch.relu(self.fc1(t))
            t = torch.relu(self.fc2(t))
            t = torch.relu(self.out(t))
            t = torch.sigmoid(t)
            return t
   ```

this is my neural network class, DQN

The problem am facing is that even after training the model, it is choosing the same action for every state-next state pairs.

```
def train(num_episodes = 5000, batch_size = 256, policy_net = DQN(), target_net = DQN()):
    #batch_size = 256
    gamma = 0.999
    eps_start = 1
    eps_end = 0.001
    eps_decay = 0.0001
    target_update = 10
    memory_size = 100000
    lr = 0.001
    #num_episodes = 2000

    man = GameManager() #this class contains all game related functions i.e game_over(), make_move()
    strategy = EpsilonGreedyStrategy(eps_start, eps_end, eps_decay) #epsilon greedy strategy
    agent = Agent(strategy) # agent that fetches action from policy net
    memory = ReplayMemory(memory_size) # memory for storing states

    #policy_net = DQN() policy network
    #target_net = DQN() target network
    target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())
    target_net.eval()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(params=policy_net.parameters(), lr=lr)

    episode_durations = []
    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        man.reset() # resets the game to initial condition
        state = man.get_state() # get current board state
        y = state.detach().clone()

        for timestep in count():
            action = agent.select_action(y, policy_net) #select random action or get it from policy network
            man.step(action) # take action
            next_state = man.get_state()
            y1 = next_state.detach().clone()
            memory.push(Experience(y, y1, torch.tensor(man.reward))) #push states to replay memory
            y = next_state.detach().clone()

            if memory.can_provide_sample(batch_size):
                experiences = memory.sample(batch_size)
                states, next_states, rewards = extract_tensors(experiences)
                #print(policy_net(states).max(dim=1))
                current_q_values, current_q_indices = QValues.get_current(policy_net, states) # get q value for the current states
                next_q_values, next_q_indices = QValues.get_next(target_net, next_states) # get q value for the next states
                target_q_values = (next_q_values * gamma) + rewards

                loss = F.mse_loss(current_q_values, target_q_values)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                #print(loss)

            if man.done:
                if man.reward == 1:
                    win_count = win_count + 1
                elif man.reward == -1:
                    lose_count = lose_count + 1
                elif man.reward == 0:
                    draw_count = draw_count + 1

                episode_durations.append(timestep)
                #print("episode over")
                break

        if episode % target_update == 0:
            target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())
```

`train function` is used to store states and then train the network

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, strategy):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.strategy = strategy


    def select_action(self, state, policy_net):
        rate = self.strategy.get_exploration_rate(self.current_step)
        self.current_step += 1

        if rate > random.random():
            #print(torch.tensor(random.randrange(9)).item())
            return torch.tensor(random.randrange(9))
        else:
            with torch.no_grad():
                print(policy_net(state).argmax().item())
                return policy_net(state).argmax()
```

and this is where the agent is choosing the same action for every possible state, the line `print(policy_net(state).argmax().item())` prints the same action value for every state.

[github link to my project](https://github.com/algo-byte/tic-tac-toe-deep-q-learning-implementation-work-in-progress-/blob/main/game.py)

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem here, but I would remove the last relu. The output should go directly to the sigmoid. The reason is that the relu will remove all negative neuron values and therefore the sigmoid output will be limited to [0.5, 1), which is not ideal. Actually, since the model is so small, I would try to swap the other two relus for sigmoids as well.

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi, thanks for the reply I tried removing the relu function but the problem seems to persist. Also swapping relu with sigmoid didn't help. Do you think there could be any other problem with the program?

Comment: Sorry, Christmas vacation here, I'm a bit slow. The problem intrigues me, I will download the code from your Github in the coming days and will try to play with it a bit. I will let you know if I find anything.